# How to Create and change Dynamic shared and periodic_tasks tasks by api in Django

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, scheduled-tasks

I'm using Celery to run periodic_tasks and schedule task.

api_view.py:

```
from .tasks import first, first_periodic_tasks


def index(request):
    first.delay('test')
    #first_periodic_tasks
    # i want to change first_periodic_tasks time or create new one
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Tasks.py

```
@shared_task
def first(city):
    print(city)


@celery_app.on_after_finalize.connect
def first_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute=0, hour=15),
        job.s('test'),
    )


@celery_app.task
def job(arg):
    print(arf)
```

**I want to create `second_periodic_tasks` dynamic using my  Django REST api.**

AND

**I also want to change `first_periodic_tasks` run time using my Django REST api.**

How can i do this using Celery?

Comment: What is "my api" exactly and what have you tried so far?

Comment: i want to create new periodic task using  Django REST apis

Comment: You have no code showing anything like that. As it is now, your question is too broad.

Comment: i updated my question please look and help me please

Comment: @JustChill You can use `apply_async` and define when to run the task.